# Django: How to create a superuser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Good Day,

I am trying to create a custom user model with AbstractBaseUser.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

# Create your models here.


class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **other):

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            **other
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email adress'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I used the documentation to create it.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/

I deleted my database, made makemigrations, migrate and created a superuser like in the screenshot:
[image]

With the password 'admin' and email 'admin@admin.com'.
But it doesnt work as you see in the screenshot.

Do you know the issue?

Thank you very much! :-)

Edit:
settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'abstractuser',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'abstractuser.NewUser'
```

Comment: Did you update your `settings.py` to use your custom user model for authentication? Can you provide the relevant parts of your `settings.py` ?

Comment: Hmmm. I can't test thoroughly right now, but I think what you have _should_ work. It seems to follow the example code from the docs, as long as you also have the `admin.py` changes (though I don't think they're needed for logging in). -- The only thing I can think of that might cause this is if perhaps you forgot to run migrations. The other might be the difference in how the `is_staff` attribute is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

The [`is_staff` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.is_staff) is what determines whether the user may login to the admin site. In your code, you're not setting this property to `True` when creating superusers.

You need to either set `user.is_staff = True` in your `create_superuser` function *or* replace the `is_staff` field with a property that reads from `is_admin`.

```
def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):

    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        username=username,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_staff = True  # can access the admin site
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you very much!

Comment: Do you as well know, why is shows 'You don’t have permission to view or edit anything' after signing in to the admin dashboard?

Comment: @rPi hmmm. I'm not 100% sure, but my guess might be that your models aren't registered to the admin site or you need to configure permissions (since you're using the permission mixin) If you can't figure it out after troubleshooting yourself, maybe consider asking another question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the following methods to your Custom User Model.
These are the methods required by django-admin panel.
Source -
[django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/)

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin
```